# Porque esse erro na hora de decorar meu Container no flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

> Cannot provide both a color and a decoration The color argument is
>   just a shorthand for "decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: color)".
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart': Failed assertion: line
>   317 pos 15: 'color == null || decoration == null'

Comment: Poderia postar o código para podermos analisar melhor ?

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro quer dizer que você não pode usar a propriedade `color` junto com a `decoration.color`...

**Exemplos**

Pintar um `Container`

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  width:100,
  height: 100
)
```

Criar um `Container` com bordas arredondadas

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
        topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0)
    )
)
```

**Explicação**

O `Container` possuí a propriedade `Color` para facilitar as coisas para nós, assim não precisamos criar um `BoxDecoration` apenas para mudar a cor...

Mas quando precisamos mudar mais coisas no `Container` nós precisamos criar o `BoxDecoration` e então o Flutter pede que utilizemos a propriedade `color` do `BoxDecoration`, pois se não o Widget "ficaria confuso" em saber de onde pegar a sua cor.

Então sempre que precisar, por exemplo, criar um `Container` azul com bordas arredondadas faça:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
        topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

O Container tem uma validação para a cor. Se estiver utilizando um `decoration` não pode utilizar o atributo `color` fora dele. Nesta caso o `color` deve ser movido para dentro do atributo de decoração.

#### Exemplo

```
Container(
  color: Colors.amber,
);
```

ou

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.amber
  )
);
```

A sintaxe acima funciona normalmente, a sintaxe abaixo causará erro pois existe o `decoration` e o `color` está fora dele.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(),
  color: Colors.amber
);
```